# SELECT data and latest stock from GROUP

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by, subquery

I have to ask my question based on the following example.

### mysql table

[image]

---

### step 1: get sales per day

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as sold, productnumber, DATE(date) AS date
FROM foo
GROUP BY productnumber, DATE(date)
ORDER BY date;
```

returns:

[image]

---

### step 2 / wanted: get sales and latest stock per day

Latest stock = last stock update per day, e.g. for productnumber 123 it's 7 on 2017-12-06:

[image]

So how to select this?

Clearly, just adding stock to the SELECT won't work:

```
SELECT stock, SUM(amount) as sold, productnumber, DATE(date) AS date
FROM foo
GROUP BY productnumber, DATE(date)
ORDER BY date;
```

It would return 0 instead of 7 on this product and on this day:

[image]

---

### LEFT JOIN? Subquery?

How to write this SQL properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way is a `join`:

```
SELECT f.*, f2.stock
FROM foo f JOIN
     (SELECT f.productnumber, SUM(f.amount) as sold, DATE(f.date) as date,
             MAX(f.date) as maxdate
      FROM foo f
      GROUP BY f.productnumber, DATE(f.date)
     ) f join
     foo f2
     ON f2.productnumber = f.productnumber AND f2.date = f.maxdate
ORDER BY date;
```